# Display Articles of Sub Categories in a Main Category PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a category table

```
cat_id, cat_name, parent_id, cat_slug
```

and I have article table as follow

```
art_id, cat_id, art_title, art_content, author_id .....
```

and my users table as

```
user_id, username, pw, .....
```

so with these data, I want to display all articles which are listed under sub category

for example:

url of main category is: mydomain.com/cat/business
url of sub category is: mydomian.com/cat/business/advertising

so when people visit the main category, then it should display the subcategories listed articles on main category even though the cat_id is not mentioned as main category. I want to list out all sub categories of business's subcategories articles on business category page.

what is the query, i should try to achieve this

help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Where does 'sub category' exist in your database?

Comment: How deep can the sub-category nesting be?

Comment: @DaOgre it's in the category table: the OP has `parent_id` there, which, I assume, will be `null` for top level categories and contain the parent category id otherwise.

Comment: sounds like a pretty straightforward query then.  When you're inside a category $cat `$query = SELECT a.art_whatever FROM articles a, categories c WHERE c.cat_id = a.cat_id AND c.parent_id = '$cat'";`

Comment: @AleksG Sub category is 1 level deep

Comment: @DaOgre thanks, I tried this version, it did not help me, rather all articles disappeared even on sub category url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to get your categories...

If your category nesting is only two levels deep (parent and child) or you are only interested in direct sub-categories (i.e. not subcategories of subcategories), then your SQL is pretty simple:

```
SELECT cat_id FROM category_table WHERE cat_id = $catid OR parent_id = $catid
```

If your nesting is deeper, then you'll need to recursively query as far down as your category nesting goes.  For example, if you limit yourself to 3 levels, you can do this with SQL like this:

```
SELECT cat_id FROM category_table ct1
WHERE cat_id = $catid OR parent_id = $catid
OR parent_id in (SELECT cat_id FROM category_table WHERE parent_id = ct1.cat_id)
```

Similarly, for a 4-level deep nesting, you can make the SQL even more complicated:

```
SELECT cat_id FROM category_table ct1
WHERE cat_id = $catid OR parent_id = $catid
OR parent_id in (SELECT cat_id FROM category_table ct2 WHERE parent_id = ct1.cat_id
                 OR parent_id in
                 (SELECT cat_id FROM category_table ct3 WHERE parent_id = ct2.cat_id))
```

And so on.

If you do not have a fixed nesting depth, then you'll need to do the looping in the code.

Once you have all categories, then you query articles.  So for a simple 2-level dependency, you'll get

```
SELECT * FROM article_table
WHERE cat_id in (SELECT cat_id FROM category_table WHERE cat_id = $catid OR parent_id = $catid)
```

Similarly, for a 3-level nesting, you'll get

```
SELECT * FROM article_table
WHERE cat_id in
    (SELECT cat_id FROM category_table ct1
     WHERE cat_id = $catid OR parent_id = $catid
     OR parent_id in (SELECT cat_id FROM category_table WHERE parent_id = ct1.cat_id))
```

And so on...

Comment: you are suggesting me that, first i query the cat table and then fetch the articles based on the queried cat table? Thanks

Comment: @sammry No, you can do it all in one go.  I just explained the reasoning.  Read my post through to the end.

Comment: no, its not working for me, i think, am doing something wrong or may be out of the logic box

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from category where parent_id=cat_id
```

Here for a given cat_id,it will fetch all the sub_categories for this.